# Gaussian filter application in rendering algorithm

Tags: graphics, textures, render, pixel, gaussian

So I'm implementing this one rendering algorithm and part of the algorithm has the following component dealing with accessing texels from a texture the size of the screen. The code below hopefully is pretty straight forward.

```
int k = arbitrary integer;

for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
{
    for(int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
    {
        Pixel(i,j) += Texture(i + k*x, j+k*y) * G[x+1][y+1];
    }
}
```

In this case the paper I am reading classifies the function G[x][y] as a 3x3 Gaussian filter but then does not give any more information beyond that. So I was wondering if anyone here, based on what I've written here might be able to figure out how to implement a Gaussian filter that would fit this particular section of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a 3x3 2D Gaussian kernel, you can use this:

```
0.04492 0.1221  0.4492
0.1221  0.33192 0.1221
0.04492 0.1221  0.4492
```

That sums to 1, so you don't need to divide out the weight. It may be more efficient to do a 2-pass method where you first do the horizontal processing with a 1D kernel (0.1221, 0.3319, 0.1221), and then do the vertical processing with the same kernel. You may also want to try a Gaussian with a different sigma.